# Error with calendar class and generating numbers

Tags: java, random, time

I'm trying to do random number generation using the given date to create good pseudo-random numbers in Java. I decided to use the `Calendar` class and to count milliseconds in the day. This worked to some extent, but I can only get a different random value when I start the program. Running it any more times in the program will just give me the same number. I'm using `Thread.sleep()` to make sure that there is an actual difference on time, but I still get the same numbers.
Heres my method that I'm calling (from another class)

```
public long genRNG()
{
    long mask = 0xFFFF000000000000L;
    long randomValue = seed & mask;
    seed = 0x5D588B656C078965L * cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + 0x0000000000269EC3;
    return randomValue;
}
```

and here's my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    Seed key = new Seed();
    for (int x = 0; x <=10; x++)
    {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println(key.genRNG());
    }
}
```

and the given output:

```
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
-7389844038561562624
```

Comment: You are changing `seed` variable value, while returning `randomValue`.

Comment: More importantly, you're not changing `cal`.

Comment: randomValue consists of Seed though Andre

Comment: What do you mean Jon?

Comment: It seems you are setting `mask` to the same value each time and `seed` to the same value each time, so `seed & mask` yields the same value each time.

Comment: I suppose `cal` is instance of `java.util.Calendar`? Maybe `GregorianCalendar`?

Comment: So one suggestion is to do reinitialize `cal` in each call to `genRNG()`.

Comment: Yes, cal is supposed to retrieve the amount of milliseconds in the date, so it should change itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are setting `mask` to the same value each time and `seed` to the same value each time, so `seed & mask` yields the same value each time. A `Calendar` object does not automatically change its value after it has been instantiated — in other words it keeps the time it got when you constructed it (typically the time *when* it was constructed) until you explicitly change it. So one suggestion is to do reinitialize `cal` in each call to `genRNG()`.

Here I have changed `cal` to a local variable:

```
    long mask = 0xFFFF000000000000L;
    long randomValue = seed & mask;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    seed = 0x5D588B656C078965L * cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + 0x0000000000269EC3;
    return randomValue;
```

Now I can get output like:

```
0
8430738502437568512
-2453898846963499008
2916080758722396160
3291568377654411264
-1326873040214032384
-951385421282017280
1212312724692795392
-3406128693175648256
-1298444067566256128
-5916885485434699776
```

The initial 0 comes from `seed` not having been initialized. I gather it’s not a problem in your code.

I don’t think you’re there yet, though. `Calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)` always returns a value in the interval 0 through 999, so you are getting up to 1000 different “random” values. Not a lot for storing in a `long`. You may get more for instance like this:

```
    seed = 0x5D588B656C078965L * System.currentTimeMillis() + 0x0000000000269EC3;
```

If for some reason you want an *object* for the current time rather than just the `long` you get from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, if you can use Java 8, I suggest `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`. It gives you the same `long` value, but `Instant.now()` gives you an object representing the current time, much like `Calendar.getInstance()`, only more modern and more versatile if you want to use it for other purposes.

Another issue is because of the mask your value will always end in 48 zeroes in binary representation (it’s easy to see all the values are even). Maybe this is as designed?

Also I suppose there is a reason why you are not just using `java.util.Random`.

Comment: wow, this is a really good answer! thank you so much, I'd upvote but I don't have enough reputation I used Calendar because I wasn't aware of any other methods to track time, and yes, I'm trying to do my own version of a Linear Congruential random number generator.